# How to save a HashMap in a text file?

Tags: java

Here is my class of `Word` and `HashMap` object shown. I want to save it on text file in Java. Please, guide me.

```
public class Word 
{
    private String path;
    private transient int frequency;
    private List<Integer> lindex=new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

```
HashMap<String,List<Word>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Add a `toString` method which converts the map to some readable format.  You could use JSON for this.

Comment: Save it as what? ;) You need to have data representation of map.
You can save for example as json, xml, csv... Choose what format You want to save it first - then save it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson XML for this task.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    private static class Word implements Serializable {
        public void setPath(String s) {
            this.path = s;
        }
        @JsonProperty
        private String path;
        @JsonProperty
        private transient int frequency;
        @JsonProperty
        private List<Integer> lindex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, IOException {
        HashMap<String, List<Word>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList<Word>();
        Word w1 = new Word();
        Word w2 = new Word();
        Word w3 = new Word();
        w1.setPath("dev");
        w2.setPath("media");
        w3.setPath("etc");
        a.add(w1);
        a.add(w2);
        a.add(w3);
        hashMap.put("key1", a);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(new File("data.json"), hashMap);
    }
}
```

Output file `data.json`

```
{"key1":[{"path":"dev","lindex":[]},{"path":"media","lindex":[]},{"path":"etc","lindex":[]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to use [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [XMLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html), which perform bean serialization:

```
static void write(Map<?, ?> map,
                  Path path)
throws IOException {
    try (XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
            Files.newOutputStream(path)))) {

        final Exception[] exception = { null };
        encoder.setExceptionListener(e -> exception[0] = e);
        encoder.writeObject(map);

        if (exception[0] != null) {
            throw new IOException(exception[0]);
        }
    }
}

static Map<?, ?> read(Path path)
throws IOException {
    try (XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(
        new BufferedInputStream(
            Files.newInputStream(path)))) {

        final Exception[] exception = { null };
        decoder.setExceptionListener(e -> exception[0] = e);
        Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) decoder.readObject();

        if (exception[0] != null) {
            throw new IOException(exception[0]);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're simply outputting text, rather than any binary data:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
```

Write your String to it, just like you would to any output stream:

```
out.println(hashMap.toString());
```

Comment: That will write the HashMap data, but how is one supposed to read it back?  Remember, keys and values themselves might contain `=`, `[`, `]`, and `,`.